# Why does IE (and Firefox 4) not properly wrap this? (hasLayout??)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, haslayout

I have the following (http://jsfiddle.net/gVZwr/4/):

```
<div>
    <label>From</label>
    <span>Some Content Goes Here</span>
</div>

span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

in IE8/9, the label and span don't align (the label is lower than the span).

Why???  I can fix it by putting `overflow:hidden` on the label, but I want to know what's causing it.  I tried the old “hasLayout” fixes, such as putting `zoom:1` on the label, but nothing seems to fix it except, specifically, `overflow`.

Comment: FYI: I tried this in FF4 and the result is the same as in IE8. Chrome is different, though.

Comment: hasLayout is long gone. I think the last version that used that was IE 7. Well, you then probably still have it in Quirks and Compatibility modes, but I hope you *do* test in the primary rendering mode ...

Comment: Also note: adding `overflow:hidden` to the label does not fix it by itself. It also needs `display:inline-block` (at least in my tests)

Comment: @Joey - I know `hasLayout` is long gone, but this seems to be a similar rendering issue since in IE<=7 setting `overflow:-anything-` would trigger `hasLayout=true`, and here I'm seeing that `overflow` is causing the browser to kick into a different rendering mode... or something.
@jwd - Thanks, I actually hadn't tested this exact case in FF yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `inline-block` elements with `overflow` set to anything other than `visible` have a baseline that's at the bottom edge of the box (actually, of the bottom margin of the box) instead of having a baseline at the text baseline.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align the very last paragraph.

Then that baseline, which basically corresponds to the bottom edge of the `span`'s border in your situation is aligned with the baseline of the `label`, which is the actual baseline of the text in the label.  So the text of the `label` ends up below the text of the `span` visually.

WebKit doesn't follow the spec here and seems to be unwilling to change that because there's WebKit-specific non-Web content that depends on its current behavior.  That's why you're not seeing the effect in WebKit.

Opera 11 does the same thing as IE and Firefox here, per spec.

Oh, and as far as fixing, you can either change the vertical-align of the `label` or take out the `overflow` on the `span`, assuming you actually need the `span` to be `inline-block`.

Answer (score 3):

Try vertical-align: http://jsfiddle.net/gVZwr/2/

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea why `vertical-align:bottom` on the ___span___ causes the ___label___ to move?  Also, I'm not so interested in a solution (as I said in the Q, I already have one), but the cause... Especially now that I see FF exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: From the looks of it (I added borders to make it more clear), the span has an invisible `margin-bottom` or something that `vertical-align:-anything-` removes...?  (as does doing a number of other things...)

Comment: Not exactly. As Paud D. Waite remarked, the `inline-block` display causes this odd behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

How about making the `<label>` `inline-block` as well? I think `inline-block` affects the vertical alignment of elements.

(And, going off-topic, see [@josmh’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052573/why-does-ie-not-properly-wrap-this-haslayout/6052604#6052604) about what `<label>` is for, i.e. labelling form fields.)

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to affect the `span` element's vertical align, hence my suggestion to set its vertical alignment to `bottom`. Removing the display property works just as well though.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the `<label>` is meant to be [bound to something](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9). Here are [some examples](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa052206.htm).

Comment: `<label>` is indeed meant to be associated with a form field, but I don’t think that’s causing the layout issue.

Comment: Yeah, this is a stripped-down example.  It is bound to something in the actual use-case, but that's not what's causing the layout issue.

Comment: @cwolves: out of interest, is it associated with a form field? Because (IIRC) nothing else makes sense as per the spec.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, the actual code is more like : `<div><label /><input /><span /></div>`, I just stripped it to the example above for simplicity.